# Using the type system to enforce coordinate boundaries in Rust

Tags: math, types, rust

I'm trying to take a page out of Haskell's book and use the Rust type system to ensure values used in a coordinate system remain within a certain range, and catch out-of-range errors at compile time.

Imagine a coordinate pair type like this:

```
struct Coordinates {
    x: i64,
    y: i64,
}
```

With such a system, any valid 64-bit signed integer could occupy my coordinate system, instead of, say, just `0-50`. I could put checks in the code throughout the use of this type to ensure coordinates stay within the "valid" range, but problems here would have to be caught at runtime, rather than compile time, and there's the possibility I'd miss some tricky way of sneaking in invalid values.

Sure, it's a slightly convoluted example, but imagine if instead of coordinates on a map these were memory addresses on a RAM card. Suddenly the ability to mess with sneaking in values out of the allowed range could have disastrous security consequences, so why not solve this at compile time?

Instead, I'd like to do something like this, dynamically generating bounded types at compile time:

```
struct Coordinates {
    x: i64bounded!(-50, 100),
    y: i64bounded!(-25, 75),
}
```

Now I know that in order for this type to work, I'd need to overload all of the mathematical operators to add in bounds checks and, say, mark the variable as illegal somehow if it escaped the bounds so the compiler would complain. The real problem comes down to mathematical closure. The idea that there is the possibility for user-submitted values to cause a type error would likely require optionals to mark a variable as invalid, with all future steps rejecting use of a `None` optional value.

Is it possible to do such a thing in Rust? How would you go about doing it?

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/671

Comment: It is impossible to enforce this at compile-time. For example, if you receive an out-of-range value from a database query or user input. The old RFC that @Stargateur has linked discusses this a little. A future feature could have a compile error when it can be proven that the value is out of range (e.g. a literal) or could optimise the run-time checks when it can prove the value is in range. But the general case would always rely on run-time checks.